# What's the best way to implement a custom BinaryPublisher in DD4T?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, dd4t, dxa, binary

I am working on a PoC using the Reference Implementation as the guideline. I am checking the way binaries get published and I can see they get the tcm id appended to their file name. In my case I want to be able to control the location they are published to (I will use structure groups for that) as well as the file name they get when published.

I know you can implement a custom `BinaryPublisher`, but I want to understand whether I need to download the DD4T templates source code, add my own, modify the `Dynamic*.cs` using the `BinaryPublisher` and reference mine or I can use some other mechanism to override the default behavior.

```
protected BinaryPublisher BinaryPublisher
{
    get
    {
        if (_binaryPublisher == null)
        {
            _binaryPublisher = new MyBinaryPublisher(Package, Engine);
        }
        return _binaryPublisher;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you use DD4T publishing templates in your current PoC implementation? Or you are thinking of using DD4T, just for implementing custom binary publisher? Based on that you can choose to use or not use DD4T. We use custom binary publisher with DD4T and we use ECL for getting the binaries from a DAM system. So, based on your implementation, answers will vary. May be a little more information, will help get to an answer

Comment: @Jaime : Can you share what approach you took for the custom Binary publisher? We have a similar requirement to work with DD4T 2.0.8 version, https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/custom-binary-publisher-with-an-older-version-dd4t

Comment: I believe this is now part of DD4T 2.0, you can "overwrite" the default binary publishing mechanism. Some examples: https://yatb.mitza.net/2016/01/a-dd4tnet-implementation-custom-binary.html, https://yatb.mitza.net/2016/01/a-dd4tnet-implementation-custom-binary_25.html